# Apache Karaf - Received fatal alert: protocol_version

Tags: java, apache-karaf

I am using Apache Karaf 4.0.3 with Java 1.7. When I start it, I get the following error:

> Received fatal alert: protocol_version

i.e.

> 2020-02-27 14:46:58,690 | ERROR | lixDispatchQueue |
>   FeatureDeploymentListener        | 27 -
>   org.apache.karaf.deployer.features - 4.0.3 | Unable to install
>   features java.io.IOException: Error resolving artifact
>   org.ops4j.pax.web:pax-web-features:xml:jettyconfig:4.2.3: Could not
>   transfer artifact
>   org.ops4j.pax.web:pax-web-features:xml:jettyconfig:4.2.3 from/to
>   central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/): Received fatal alert:
>   protocol_version

I have tried setting the following in the `.../apache-karaf-4.0.3/bin/karaf` file.

```
-Dhttps.protocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"
```

i.e.

```
exec "$JAVA" $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.endorsed.dirs="${JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS}" -Djava.ext.dirs="${JAVA_EXT_DIRS}" -Dkaraf.instances="${KARAF_HOME}/instances" -Dkaraf.home="$KARAF_HOME" -Dkaraf.base="$KARAF_BASE" -Dkaraf.data="$KARAF_DATA" -Dkaraf.etc="$KARAF_ETC" -Djava.io.tmpdir="$KARAF_DATA/tmp" -Dhttps.protocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" -Djava.util.logging.config.file="$KARAF_BASE/etc/java.util.logging.properties" $KARAF_OPTS $OPTS -classpath "$CLASSPATH" $MAIN "$@"
```

**Question**

Any ideas on how I can resolve this error?

Thanks

More info:

[image]

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_80"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)


$ mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: /Users/richardmarais/Development/java/Maven/apache-maven-3.6.3
Java version: 1.7.0_80, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.15.3", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

My colleagues at work, have the exact same setup, but theirs works.

Answer (score 0):

I installed the Karaf webconsole, and it suddenly started working. I cannot explain why.

https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/webconsole